# plotting length of time for each task

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I am trying to make a chart that display how long each task ran for

I have one row per task

```
task     |   Start_time |    Finish_time

Task 1    |  09:00:00    |   09:45:00
Task 2   |  09:20:00    |   13:15:00
```

So I am trying to have the tasks on the x axis and the the y axis be 24 hour tick marks and a bar have the time it ran during those times.

so far I have :

```
ggplot(sas_program_data, aes(xmin = Start_time, xmax = Finish_time, fill = factor(task)))
```

[image]

Comment: I just added the code I attempted but the graph doesn't come out right

Comment: Your code has a few issues. First, `ggplot` takes the arguments `x = `, `y = `, not `xmin` or `xmax`. Second, you haven't added a geom, such as `geom_col`. Third, the variable type of the times (_e.g._ character, Period) is not clear from your example data.

Comment: Do you need it to be a line? Line wouldn't really be the best way to show this I think, columns/bar chart might be better

Comment: bar or just dots would be ok but I can't ge tit to show whichever way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a column graph to show this type of information. Something like this:

```
 library(magrittr)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(plyr)

 df <- data.frame(task=c("T1", "T2"),
             start=c("09:00:00", "09:20:00"),
             finish=c("09:45:00", "13:15:00")) %>%
    mutate(diff=strptime(df$finish, format = "%H:%M:%S")-strptime(df$start, format = "%H:%M:%S"))

 ggplot(aes(task, diff), data=df[, c("task", "diff")]) +
   geom_col()
```

You can add colour in the `geom_col()` bit as well if you want by adding `aes(fill=task)`.

If you just want points you can replace the `geom_col()` with `geom_point()` and `diff` with `finsih` you will just get 2 points:

```
 ggplot(aes(task, finish), data=df[, c("task", "finish")]) +
   geom_point()
```

Edit: thanks for updating with a picture. Try this:

```
 ggplot() +
   geom_segment(aes(y=start, yend=finish, x=task, xend=task), data = df, size=2)
```

You can muck around with the look of the lines and the specific axis ticks, but this should get you started.

Comment: is there a way to plot two y values instead of showing the difference?

Comment: ummm, I'm not exactly sure what that would look like. It also would be hard to compare any of the lines as they don't start at the same time. Can you include an image of what you would like it to look like? Even if it's shoddily done in paint, it would be easier to use that as a starting point

Comment: also look up swimmers plots. They might be a good way to show your data

Comment: I added code to just get the dots...not as useful though imho

Comment: I added a picture of a desired output

Comment: updated to include a new answer. Does that work better for you?

Comment: Yes! I didn't realize there's a geom_segment option. I haven't used ggplot2 much. Thanks

Comment: no worries, only discovered it a few days ago myself :)